# use of android device binaries while building Android Open Source Project

Tags: device, binaries, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to build the AOSP for android Oreo,in the software requirement section it is mentioned about the following device binaries-

(1)Preview binaries (blobs)
  (2)Factory images 
  (3)Binary hardware support files branches
  (4)OTA images

Without including these binaries,I am able to build the code successfully but while running the emulator it is not started.
As per my knowledge, we do not require these binaries in case we are using an emulator,is it necessary to include them?

link followed->[link for software requirements](https://source.android.com/source/requirements)

Answer (score 0):

Device binaries are mandatory for both emulator as well as hardware device,the avd in the android studio and the binaries should be of same configuration.